# Laravel Task Scheduling - Cron job is not running scheduled commands

Tags: php, laravel, cron, centos

I have a Laravel **5.7** project in production on CentOS. The project schedules one task:

```
$schedule->command('import:producers --create --update --afterOrEqual="-5 minutes"')
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->appendOutputTo(
        storage_path('logs/schedule/producers_import.log')
    );
```

According to last log inside `logs/schedule/producers_import.log`, this worked perfectly until **2019-05-30** when server was restarted for some reason.

Now the scheduled task is not running "automatically" by cron job but if I `cd` to `my-project` and manually run at right time:

```
$ php artisan schedule:run
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' import:producers --create --update --afterOrEqual="-5 minutes" >> '/var/www/my-project/storage/logs/schedule/producers_import.log' 2>&1
```

> The above command generates a new log into `logs/schedule/producers_import.log`.

This is strange for me because the cron log shows up that the scheduler is being called every minute as expected:

```
$ cat /var/log/cron

...
Jun 19 08:57:01 my-server-name CROND[29679]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 08:58:01 my-server-name CROND[29724]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 08:59:01 my-server-name CROND[29739]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 09:00:01 my-server-name CROND[29754]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jun 19 09:00:01 my-server-name CROND[29755]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /etc/SomeOtherScript.sh)
Jun 19 09:00:01 my-server-name CROND[29756]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 09:00:32 my-server-name crontab[29784]: (admin) LIST (admin)
Jun 19 09:01:01 my-server-name CROND[29787]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 19 09:01:01 my-server-name CROND[29788]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 09:01:01 my-server-name run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[29787]: starting 0anacron
Jun 19 09:01:01 my-server-name run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[29798]: finished 0anacron
Jun 19 09:02:01 my-server-name CROND[29813]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jun 19 09:03:01 my-server-name CROND[29836]: (admin) CMD (php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

> Laravel task is never called because it doesn't generate any log into `logs/schedule/producers_import.log` and the database never changed with the command side-effects.

The (active) cron service since **2019-05-30**:

```
$ systemctl status crond
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-05-30 17:28:05 -04; 2 weeks 5 days ago
 Main PID: 27650 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─27650 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Jun 18 11:26:38 my-server-name systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Jun 18 11:26:38 my-server-name crond[27650]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with f...d.)
Jun 18 11:26:38 my-server-name crond[27650]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jun 18 11:26:38 my-server-name crond[27650]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at comput...p.)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

The cron entries:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * php /var/www/my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed. There is some other service to check status?

How can I better monit cron jobs to discover why it's not calling Laravel task after **2019-05-30**?

Comment: what if you changed  ">> /dev/null 2>&1" to the log file path just to check if the log is generated ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet why? this is recommended by Laravel docs and it worked normally before.

Comment: never used laravel. So am assuming when you send to dev/null, laravel automatically generates the log ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet I imagine that it is replaced by `->appendOutputTo(
        storage_path('logs/schedule/producers_import.log')
    );` path.

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi did you manage to figure out?